# Mouse hook, respond only when clicked on Button

Tags: c#, mouse-hook

I developed C# application which responds to low level mouse clicks. I used mouse hook to do this. The application is working fine, whenever i click any window it responds and perform some task. But i want to do a modification here. I wanted to respond the mouse clicks whenever the click is performed on any buttons on the window. If i click on plain area of window it should not respond. Currently it responds wherever i click. I could not find how to identify whether i clicked on a button or not.

This is my code :

```
private IntPtr SetHook(MouseHookHandler proc)
    {
        using (ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
    }
    private IntPtr HookFunc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                if (LeftButtonUp != null)
                    LeftButtonUp((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)));
            if (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                if (RightButtonUp != null)
                    RightButtonUp((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)));

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        MouseHookHandler lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for something along the lines of [WindowFromPoint](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.windowfrompoint).

Call that to see what is under the mouse cursor, then you can query it for whatever properties you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Now i added the following code :
      IntPtr win = WindowFromPoint(ms.pt);
I got the window handle as win. Now can i use GetChildAtPoint() by passing cursor position for the 'win' handle? or any other suggestion ?

Comment: I tried converting intptr 'win' as Control using ControlFromHandle and it always returns null. If it was successful i could invoke GetChildAtPoint() method.

Comment: ControlFromHandle only works for your normal process. Try GetClassName or GetWindowText (both native functions, so use pinvoke)